In Opencart Twig what is the proper way to add elements to the head tag only on pages that require them?
I am trying to add style and/or script elements in the head tag from header.twig but I don't want them on every page that uses header.twig. Product.twig should get only the styles and scripts which apply to it and other pages likewise. How do I do that in Opencart's Twig?
I thought maybe I could use extends or embed or filter somehow but I don't how to do that in Opencart's version of Twig.

you can use
$this->document->addScript
$this->document->addStyle

directly from the controller page to add styles and javascript files to header only on this page
for example in product.php
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js');

$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/magnific-popup.css');

this will add style and js file in the head only on product page

Nice! That's really cool! I'll Give that a try.
